# jasper report with unicode characters throwing illegal argument exception

Tags: grails, unicode, jasper-reports

I have a web application developed in grails framework. In it there are some reports developed using jasper report. The reports are being called from grails controller using jasper plugin. The reports were rendering from the web application without no issue.

Some days ago I implemented SSL in my tomcat server on which this application is running. After implementing SSL the reports which contain unicode characters throwing the following error:

[image]

In the server log I found the following related to it-

> 2021-12-24 13:34:24,864 [https-openssl-apr-443-exec-1147] ERROR
> errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - IllegalArgumentException occurred
> when processing request: [POST] /reportCenter/callReport The Unicode
> character [?] at code point [2,459] cannot be encoded as it is outside
> the permitted range of 0 to 255.. Stacktrace follows:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The Unicode character [?] at code
> point [2,459] cannot be encoded as it is outside the permitted range
> of 0 to 255.

But the other reports which don't contain unicode characters are working properly. I've googled the issue for hours but no luck. Can anybody help please.

Answer (score 0):

Your config file or `JRXML` needs to have the encoding declared. Try UTF-8 or  `ISO-8859-1` (which is latin-1)

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.character.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
```

Depending on if it's a `csv` or `pdf`, there's different property names, search for the word 'encoding' on this page:

source: https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-set-encoding-exports-resolve-odd-and-incorrect-characters-output